# VS Code error `failed to run build scripts` when using Rust-Analyzer only on one specific project

Tags: rust, vscode-extensions, rust-cargo, tauri, rust-analyzer

My company just switched on a new repo the Rust project I'm working on, to merge it with a Tauri project, and VS Code now gave me this error:

```
Failed to run build scripts
```

I can compile, run my project or use `cargo check` to see the warnings/error but Rust Analyzer is not working and it's very annoying for me to run `cargo check` every time i need to check my code.

This error occurs only on this repo, which contains a Rust workspace separate in two folders: one Tauri/Rust project and one basic Rust project.

`Cargo.toml` at the root:

```ini
[workspace]

members = [
    "builder",
    "studio/src-tauri"
]
```

Error details:

```
[ERROR rust_analyzer::lsp_utils] failed to run build scripts:
The following warnings were emitted during compilation:


error: failed to run custom build command for `cairo-sys-rs v0.15.1`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/home/korocouille/Sogilis/IReflex/reflex2/target/debug/build/cairo-sys-rs-decf14405d906ced/build-script-build` (exit status: 1)
  --- stdout
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CAIRO_NO_PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_PATH
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
  cargo:warning=`"pkg-config" "--libs" "--cflags" "cairo" "cairo >= 1.14"` did not exit successfully: exit status: 1
  error: could not find system library 'cairo' required by the 'cairo-sys-rs' crate

  --- stderr
  Package cairo was not found in the pkg-config search path.
  Perhaps you should add the directory containing `cairo.pc'
  to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
  No package 'cairo' found
  Package cairo was not found in the pkg-config search path.
  Perhaps you should add the directory containing `cairo.pc'
  to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
  No package 'cairo' found
```

I tried to uninstall and re-install Rust-Analyzer, switch to pre-release or older version, delete my target folder, run a `cargo clean` cmd but nothing changed, and I can't find any solution.

Comment: Does it compile successfully when you run `cargo build`?

Comment: Yes all work well at the compile time ! The error ocur only on VS Code with this extension

Comment: Is your integrated terminal the same shell as your OS terminal?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
It was because the environment paths from export-esp.ps1 script, only added temporarily.

So I added them manually in windows. and now it seems to work.

Comment: Ok thank i'll try this but ... how do i can manually change it ?
Sorry if it's an obvious question, im not that much familiar with that

Answer (score 0):

If you are on windows search for "environment variables" and click on the button on the almost bottom right named "environment variables".
Then click on path in user variable and click edit.
Then just add the paths without the code and "'s

Hope it helps

Edit: I would have added as a comment, but I dont have enought rep to do so.